# Show that $A := \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : -\sqrt{2} \le x \le \sqrt{2}\}$ is open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$. $A$ with the induced topology of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

Show that $A := \{x \in \mathbb{Q} :  -\sqrt{2} \le x \le \sqrt{2}\}$ is open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Only using the definitions of closed and open, show that this is true. I am having troubles finding the open balls contained in this set. And I can't remember any argument for the closed case. $A$ with the induced topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ as subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is your topology over $\mathbb{Q}$? I assume it is the order topology, but you should state it in your question.

Comment: @uniquesolution every subset of the rationals is countable, however there exist open subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the subspace topology.

Comment: Open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Leonardo, to prove it is closed, consider the function $f(x) = x^2$, and the fact that $[0,2]$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide a sketch to the problem and you can fill in the details.

Consider a sequence of points, $\{x_i\}$, converging to $\sqrt{2}$ such that each $x_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and each $x_i$ is between $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Similary, find $\{y_i\}$ such that each $y_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, $-\sqrt{2}<y_i<0$, $y_i \to -\sqrt{2}$.

Consider $\bigcup^\infty_{i=1}(y_i,x_i)$. Why is this set open?

Now we show that the compliment is open. Consider $\{a_i\}$ $\to -\sqrt{2}$, where $a_i < -\sqrt{2}$ and $\{b_i\}\to \sqrt{2}$ where $\sqrt{2}<b_i$ where each $a_i$,$b_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Consider $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (-\infty, a_i)$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (b_i, \infty)$. Why is the union of these two sets open?

Thus, we have shown that a set and its compliment (in $\mathbb{Q}$) are open. Put these facts together and you can solve your question.